# How to retrieve only keys at specific level of nesting from MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

MongoDB collection:

```
directory: {
  subDirectory: {
    SubSubdirectory: {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
  someString: 'lorem...'
  ...
},
anotherDirectory: {
  ...
}
```

There might be up to 20 levels of nesting.
Strings length (e.g. `someString` in example) might be from few words till 100k characters.

1. How do i retrieve only keys from this structure without values?
2. How do i retrieve keys only level by level? E.g. first, i want to retrieve only root keys (`directory`, `anotherDirectory`, ...), then all keys in `directory` (`subDirectory`, `someString`, ...), etc.

I need this because i also want to perform full-text search in any level of nesting. For example, i want to search through all of the data within `subDirectory` or only within `anotherDirectory` etc.

How do i do this? If there are better ways to organize data in this collection or there are more suitable databases than MongoDB for this case - that's also will be helpful!